# Class shared properties values are different when called from Project A then B, how so?

Tags: vb.net

I have three projects, let's call them `Client`, `Service` and `Execute`.

Both `Client` and `Service` references `Execute`.

`Client` is a windows forms application. While first loading, it calls a shared method in a class called `ParametersManager` which fills four parameters in a class called `Parameters`.

```
Public Class Parameters
    Public Shared Property FirstProperty As Integer
    Public Shared Property SecondProperty As Integer
End Class

Public Class ParametersManager
    Public Shared Sub FillParameters()
        'In real scenario, I am just sending the parameters as arguments to the method. 
        Parameters.FirstProperty = 1
        Parameters.SecondProperty = 2
    End Sub
End Class
```

So when the application starts, it will call `FillParameters` from `Execute`.
I did debug the application, and when this method finish executing, the properties has the exact values that I gave them.

In one of the forms of the `Client` application, I am calling the `Service` which is an `asmx` Web Service. `Service` now calls a method from `Execute` project, let's call it `UsePropertiesDoingSomething`.

```
Public Class UseProperties
    Public Shared Function UsePropertiesDoingSomething() as Integer
        Return Parameters.FirstProperty + Parameters.SecondProperty
    End Function
End Class
```

My problem is that when I call this function from the service, the properties are both equal to `0`, not the values I have previously filled when the `Client` application first run.

How did I lose the the values? Shouldn't the values be saved in the `Execute` scope? How can I make sure not to lose them?

For testing purposes, I filled the parameters at the start of the `Service`, now when the `Service` calls the `UseProperties` the values are kept, but when called from the `Client`, the values are lost again.

Comment: These are two separate applications, they do not share memory with each other, hence they have their own values for all of the shared variables.

Comment: *"How did I lose the the values?"* - You didn't.  You have two applications.  One set its values, and they're there.  The other one never set its values, so it has the defaults of `0`.  *"Shouldn't the values be saved in the `Execute` scope?"* - There is no such scope.  You have two applications.  One set its values, the other didn't.  *"How can I make sure not to lose them?"* - If you want to share data between multiple applications, take a look at using a database.  Or any other medium for persisting data outside of the application.  In-memory variables are not shared between applications.

Comment: @David, they are saved in the database, but it's our architecture that makes us use them as class parameters, so we don't query the database each now and then.  It's like caching the data. I guess the idea is now more clear for me. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this purpose you have explore AppDomain and Execution context.

1. Shared does not means that it is shared between application or project. It is shared for specific application domain.
2. If same application domain load same library then it will be shared otherwise not as other application domain has it's own copy.  (At least in .net it will not cross AppDomain boundry).

In your case Window Form has different Application Domain and ASMX in Web Service so it has different Application Domain so it will not be shared.

Comment: I thought `Shared` (i.e `static`) will hold it's own domain. I guess I am mistaken. To fix this, I have to fill the parameters both from the `Service` and `Client`?

Comment: First glance yes. There are many solution but it is different question altogether but you have to create one common service that both can access and that common service cache data.

Comment: Well, it would be more logical to use a common service. Sadly, I have to go with both `Service` and `Client` caching the data seperatly. After all those parameters will never change unless manually changed in the DB.